# How to create a intersection between two interfaces in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I am trying to create a dictionary, with its value being a combination of two interfaces.

What i am trying to do looks something like this:

```
public interface IA { };
public interface IB { };

public class Test {
    public Dictionary<int, <IA,IB>> dict;
};
```

This could create a contract that says that every item in this dict has the methods in `IA` *and* `IB`

This below method works, but could get very unmaintainable as it would require creating combinations for each interface:

```
public interface IA { };
public interface IB { };
public interface IC : IA, IB { };

public class Test {
    public Dictionary<int, IC> dict;
};
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I'd argue that the `IC` method doesn't work 100% because a class could satisfy your real requirement of implementing `IA` and `IB` without ever implementing `IC`.

Comment: IC is the *union* of IA and IB, not an intersection

Answer (score 1):

The construct that comes closest to what you're trying to do is generics with type constraints:

```
public interface IA { };
public interface IB { };

public class Test<T> where T : IA, IB
{
    public Dictionary<int, T> dict;
};
```

This enforces users of your code to provide a type that implements `IA` and `IB`, but it requires making your code generic, which may or may not be practical for your actual scenario.